# DropDownList in C# selects a default (1st) item after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with an asp:DropDownList. it is binded only if the page is not PostBack (when the page loads first).
But it keeps selecting the first item after postback.

here is some code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        getRegions();
}

private void getRegions()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconnString);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select region, emails from Regions", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmbRegion.Items.Clear();
        ListItem li = new ListItem("Select region", "Select region");
        cmbRegion.Items.Add(li);
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li = new ListItem((string)rdr["region"], (string)rdr["emails"]);
            cmbRegion.Items.Add(li);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'd recommend posting some code so we might detect where it's causing it.  You could also use ajax updatepanel to avoid postbacks but best if we see code so we can guide you directly to your issue

Comment: Does the dropdownlist have autopostback enabled?

Comment: Could you please also post the aspx? It might be related to your aspx. I remember vaguely having a same issue long time a go, and I think it was related to aspx rather than code behind. I might remember if I see the aspx.

Comment: never mind found it the problem was somewhere else. thxxx

Comment: well don't tell us or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Select region", "");
cmbRegion.Items.Insert(0,li);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cmbRegion.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("-- Select --","00"));
```